# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform after updating the firebase packages

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I updated the below packages:

- firebase_core: from ^0.5.0+1 to ^1.2.0
- cloud_firestore: from 0.14.1+3 to ^2.2.0
- firebase_auth: from ^0.18.0+1 to ^1.2.0

After updating the packages I'm getting the below error:

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#77e63):
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>
lib/screens/app_home.dart:183
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:86
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:104
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:120
#3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92
#4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[]
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Below is the output of `flutter doctor`:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on macOS 11.3.1 20E241 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Below is the code relevant to the error:

```
final coursesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').limit(10).where('courseLive', isEqualTo: true);
.
.
.
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: coursesCollection.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: kAccentColor,
            ),
          );
        }
        final courseSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs;
        List<CourseTile> courseTiles = [];
        CourseData course;
        for (var courseData in courseSnapshot) {
          course = CourseData.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot: courseData);
          final courseDocID = course.courseDocID; 
          final courseID = course.courseID; 
          final courseTitle = course.courseTitle; 
          final courseDescription = course.courseDescription; 
          final courseSubTitle = course.courseSubTitle; 
          final courseBadge = course.courseBadge; 
          final courseLevel = course.courseLevel; 
          final coursePaid = course.coursePaid; 
          final courseImage = course.courseImage;
          final courseBgColor = hexToColor(course.courseBackgroundColor); 
          final courseBgColor1 = hexToColor(course.courseBgColor1); 
          final courseBgColor2 = hexToColor(course.courseBgColor2); 
          final courseFgColor = hexToColor(course.courseFgColor); 
          final courseDeliveryFormat = course.courseDeliveryFormat;
          final courseLive = course.courseLive;

          final courseTile = CourseTile(
            cardBackgroundColor: courseBgColor,
            bgColor1: courseBgColor1,
            bgColor2: courseBgColor2,
            fgColor: courseFgColor,
            cardImage: courseImage,
            titleText: courseTitle,
            titleTextColor: courseFgColor,
            subTitleText: courseSubTitle,
            courseID: courseID,
            courseDocID: courseDocID,
          );

          courseTiles.add(courseTile);
         }
         return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: courseTiles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

I did verify the fields present in the firestore document, they do match up. Also tried reverting back the packages to their previous versions, but it still breaks.

Not sure, what needs to be done to fix this issue.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you so much for your time in advance.

### **AFTER APPLYING THE SOLUTION SUGGESTED BY VICTOR**

The `Bad state: field does not exist` error has gone. But still, I'm getting this below error.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#ef5a5):
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object>'

The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>
lib/screens/app_home.dart:183
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      CourseStream.build.<anonymous closure>
lib/screens/app_home.dart:200
#1      StreamBuilder.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:545
#2      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:124
#3      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4612
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4495
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Below is the method within the `CourseData` class which is parsing the data received from the Document Snapshot.

```
CourseData.fromDocumentSnapshot({DocumentSnapshot snapshot}) {
    courseDocID = snapshot.id;
    courseID = snapshot['courseID'];
    courseTitle = snapshot['courseTitle'];
    courseSubTitle = snapshot['courseSubTitle'];
    courseDescription = snapshot['courseDescription'];
    courseLevel = snapshot['courseLevel'];
    courseBadge = snapshot['courseType'];
    coursePaid = snapshot['coursePaid'];
    courseCategories = snapshot['courseCategories'];
    courseImage = snapshot['courseImage'];
    courseBackgroundColor = snapshot['courseBackgroundColor'];
    courseForegroundColor = snapshot['courseForegroundColor'];
    courseBgColor1 = snapshot['courseBgColor1'];
    courseBgColor2 = snapshot['courseBgColor2'];
    courseFgColor = snapshot['courseFgColor'];
    courseDeliveryFormat = snapshot['courseDeliveryFormat'];
    courseLive = snapshot['courseLive'];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to get the data from your `DocumentSnapshot`, you need to call `.data()` on the snapshot.

> **DocumentSnapshotPlatform**
>
> Contains data read from a
> document in your Firestore database.
>
> The data can be extracted by calling data() or by calling get() to get
> a specific field.
>
> [DocumentSnapshotPlatform class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/DocumentSnapshotPlatform-class.html)

**Solution:**

You can leave this line as it is:

```dart
    course = CourseData.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot: courseData);
```

and update the CourseData code to the block of code below:

```dart
    CourseData.fromDocumentSnapshot({DocumentSnapshot snapshot}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> snapshotData = snapshot.data();
    courseDocID = snapshot.id;
    courseID = snapshotData['courseID'];
    courseTitle = snapshotData['courseTitle'];
    courseSubTitle = snapshotData['courseSubTitle'];
    courseDescription = snapshotData['courseDescription'];
    courseLevel = snapshotData['courseLevel'];
    courseBadge = snapshotData['courseType'];
    coursePaid = snapshotData['coursePaid'];
    courseCategories = snapshotData['courseCategories'];
    courseImage = snapshotData['courseImage'];
    courseBackgroundColor = snapshotData['courseBackgroundColor'];
    courseForegroundColor = snapshotData['courseForegroundColor'];
    courseBgColor1 = snapshotData['courseBgColor1'];
    courseBgColor2 = snapshotData['courseBgColor2'];
    courseFgColor = snapshotData['courseFgColor'];
    courseDeliveryFormat = snapshotData['courseDeliveryFormat'];
    courseLive = snapshotData['courseLive'];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Victor for your solution. Now I don't see `bad state: field does not exist` error. Still I'm seeing the another error. I have appended the error to my original question. Could you please have a look at this. Thanks again!

Comment: I have also added the method used to parse the document snapshot present within the `CourseData` class.

Comment: @xpetta, I've updated my answer. Note that you will have to use this line of code:     `course = CourseData.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot: courseData);` instead of     `course = CourseData.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot: courseData.data());` from the previous answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Victor this worked perfectly fine. Could you please share me doc or video where I could gain more knowledge on this subject as I'm new to Flutter.

Comment: @xpetta, checkout this link: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview, it contains the documentation and the migration guide for the updated version of the firestore plugin

Comment: Brilliant! Once again thank you so much, @Victor. Highly appreciate your help. May God bless you.

Comment: Glad to help out!